# Win 8.1 Pro hangs on any driver update

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, freeze

My Win 8.1 Pro pc runs fine but I need to install some drivers and each time I try, it hangs. It does not blue screen. It freezes and hangs indefinitely about 20 seconds into the install. I'm using Admin account.

At first I thought it was just a particular set of drivers for an AverMedia TV Tuner and dismissed it as bad software from the manf but I'm finding that its drivers from anywhere i.e. intel pro wireless chipset drivers, ASUS motherboard updates, WIFI drivers etc. So it must be something more central than any particular device.

I've tried turning off real time protection on Windows Defender and disabling it via options > use this program. It's the only AV software I have.

I've checked the event viewer but nothing relevant seems to show up, possibly because the system hangs before any event logging can be written. UAC is also set to minimum.

I've done an sfc /scannow with no violations.

Since it doesn't blue screen I don't think there is any dump and I don't have the software to read the dump anyway.

I should also add that this was an update from the store. So had Win 8 installed from disk and then did the update from the Windows Store to get 8.1, if that makes any difference.

Update:

I've now tried doing a chkdsk /r and all was fine. I've tried unplugging all peripherals except keyboard, mouse and a single monitor. I've also tried swapping out my wireless mouse for a cable mouse. I've killed any process I can except for those that say doing so will make windows unstable.

None of which makes any difference.

What would be the steps to investigate this problem? I literally have nothing to go on.